# CSS3 Shapes or SVG?

Tags: css, svg

Is this possible to make using CSS3? or should I use svg?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 43px;
  background: #2f99ce;
  border-radius: 100px/190px 0 0 0;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 51px;
  height: 36px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, transparent 69%, #2f99ce 70%);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```